# how can i stop google indexing pages with urls ending with date and time

Tags: indexing

I have a website with some pages like

- www.xyz.com/product1
- www.xyz.com/product2

and www.xyz.com/product1/***date*** which can be dynamic as what user searches.

Current google is indexing

- www.xyz.com/product1
- www.xyz.com/product2
- www.xyz.com/product1/***date***

I dont want google to index  www.xyz.com/product1/***date*** urls....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe writing a proper robots meta tag:

- [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do what you want with a robots.txt at your website root directory

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /product1/*
```

Comment: i dont have this Product1/Product2 as hardcorded pages, this are dynamic pages which are created on the fly... So i wont be able to identify all this products and so wont be able create the Robot file

Answer (score 0):

If the date was in the query part ie `www.example.com/product1?date=yyyy-mm-dd` you can tell Google to ignore the date argument via Google Webmaster Tools.

Could you make the trade off and move date to query part of URL?